# Connect query from sp_whoisactive and Query Store

Tags: sql-server, query-store, sp-whoisactive

We have application which is returning result of sp_whoisactive every 1 minute. Is that any option to connect (join) results from sp_whoisactive and QueryStore ? I would like to add some stats from QueryStore to existing result from sp_whoisactive.

Comment: Does the application that runs WhoIsActive log the results to a table? Are you looking to modify the output of the stored procedure itself, or looking to do analysis after the fact on logged data?

Comment: Yes , whoisactive is logging to table, and I can do analysis after the fact on logged data.

Comment: Are you using [@get_additional_info = 1](http://whoisactive.com/docs/18_moreinfo/) or [@get_plans = 1](http://whoisactive.com/docs/11_planning/)?

Comment: I am not using  `@get_additional_info = 1` and  `@get_plans = 1` because would like to avoid long running of sp_whoisactive

Comment: Oh weird, I've been using those for many years and never had them make it run for a long time. Best of luck, then.